# Postgres query optimization (forcing an index scan)

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-optimization, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-performance

Below is my query. I am trying to get it to use an index scan, but it will only seq scan.

By the way the `metric_data` table has 130 million rows. The `metrics` table has about 2000 rows.

`metric_data` table columns:

```
  metric_id integer
, t timestamp
, d double precision
, PRIMARY KEY (metric_id, t)
```

How can I get this query to use my PRIMARY KEY index?

```
SELECT
    S.metric,
    D.t,
    D.d
FROM metric_data D
INNER JOIN metrics S
    ON S.id = D.metric_id
WHERE S.NAME = ANY (ARRAY ['cpu', 'mem'])
  AND D.t BETWEEN '2012-02-05 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP
              AND '2012-05-05 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP;
```

EXPLAIN:

```
Hash Join  (cost=271.30..3866384.25 rows=294973 width=25)
  Hash Cond: (d.metric_id = s.id)
  ->  Seq Scan on metric_data d  (cost=0.00..3753150.28 rows=29336784 width=20)
        Filter: ((t >= '2012-02-05 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
             AND (t <= '2012-05-05 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
  ->  Hash  (cost=270.44..270.44 rows=68 width=13)
        ->  Seq Scan on metrics s  (cost=0.00..270.44 rows=68 width=13)
              Filter: ((sym)::text = ANY ('{cpu,mem}'::text[]))
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

For **testing** purposes you can force the use of the index by "disabling" sequential scans - best in your current session only:

```
SET enable_seqscan = OFF;
```

Do **not** use this on a productive server. [Details in the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-ENABLE)

I quoted "disabling", because you cannot actually disable sequential table scans. But any other available option is now preferable for Postgres.  This will prove that the multicolumn index on `(metric_id, t)` *can* be used - just not as effective as an index on the leading column.

You probably get better results by switching the order of columns in your `PRIMARY KEY` (and the index used to implement it behind the curtains with it) to `(t, metric_id)`. Or create an *additional* index with reversed columns like that.

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

You do not normally have to force better query plans by manual intervention. If setting  `enable_seqscan = OFF` leads to a *much* better plan, something is probably not right in your database. Consider this related answer:

- [Keep PostgreSQL from sometimes choosing a bad query plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228326/keep-postgresql-from-sometimes-choosing-a-bad-query-plan/8229000#8229000)

Comment: Setting this flag made that query above run in 150ms compared to 45secs on my machine. Thanks!

Comment: Very instructive answer. And incredible results.

Comment: @Jeff: I added another hint to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. It should be `enable_seqscan = OFF` instead of `enable_seq_scan = OFF` in the last sentence

Comment: @muluhumu: Thanks, fixed.

Comment: There is nothing in the manual about why using hints are wrong. It only says they should be considered a temporary solution, with no basis for that statement. I'm dealing with a query that runs in 1500ms on it's own, but in a TVF with no params, it does a full scan, running over 2min. Disabling full scan fixes. It's going in to production folks! The PostgreSQL communities vilification of hints needs to end! All other majors support them. The authors of query optimizers are not infallible.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot force index scan in this case because it will not make it faster.

You currently have index on `metric_data (metric_id, t)`, but server cannot take advantage of this index for your query, because it needs to be able to discriminate by `metric_data.t` only (without `metric_id`), but there is no such index. Server can use sub-fields in compound indexes, but only starting from the beginning. For example, searching by `metric_id` will be able to employ this index.

If you create another index on `metric_data (t)`, your query will make use of that index and will work much faster.

Also, you should make sure that you have an index on `metrics (id)`.

Comment: This is not quite correct. A multi-column index *can* be used on the second field alone, too. Even though not as effective. Consider this [related question on dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6115/working-of-indexes-in-postgresql).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use:

WHERE S.NAME = ANY (VALUES ('cpu'), ('mem'))
instead of
ARRAY

like [here](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/100x-faster-postgres-performance-by-changing-1-line/)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are lacking suitable FK constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE metric_data
( metric_id integer
, t timestamp
, d double precision
, PRIMARY KEY (metric_id, t)
, FOREIGN KEY metrics_xxx_fk (metric_id) REFERENCES metrics (id)
)
```

and in table metrics:

```
CREATE TABLE metrics
( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
...
);
```

Also check if your statistics are sufficient (and fine-grained enough, since you intend to select 0.2 % of the metrics_data table)