# Updating JSON in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table with a `json` field (NOT `json-b`) and need to remove a key that exists with some records (or set the value to '').

How can I update this table to do so using SQL?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108853/updating-json-field-in-postgres) question, but it feels like there should be an easier way for this simple thing.

Comment: All keys on the root level, no nesting, right? And *always* provide your version of Postgres, please.

Answer (score 2):

First: if you are updating values a lot, `json` may be a bad choice in your database design:

- [How to perform update operations on columns of type JSONB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703476/how-to-perform-update-operations-on-columns-of-type-jsonb/26704636#26704636)

Pure SQL:

```sql
UPDATE tbl
SET    json_col = (
   SELECT concat('{', string_agg(to_json(j.key) || ':' || j.value, ','), '}')::json
   FROM   json_each(json_col) j
   WHERE  j.key <> 'delete_this_key'
   )
WHERE  json_col->>'delete_this_key' <> ''; -- only applicable rows!
```

Related:

- [How do I modify fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209625/how-do-i-modify-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype)