# Postgresql: Find values in JSON array by wildcard and comparison operators with index

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, indexing

I have a table with JSON array data I'd like to search.

```
CREATE TABLE data (id SERIAL, json JSON);

INSERT INTO data (id, json) 
  VALUES (1, '[{"name": "Value A", "value": 10}]');

INSERT INTO data (id, json) 
  VALUES (2, '[{"name": "Value B1", "value": 5}, {"name": "Value B2", "value": 15}]');
```

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18405706), i created a function, which also allows to create an index on the array data (important).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION json_val_arr(_j json, _key text)
  RETURNS text[] AS
$$
SELECT array_agg(elem->>_key)
FROM   json_array_elements(_j) AS x(elem)
$$
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

This works nicely if I want to find an entire value (eg. "Value B1"):

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE '{"Value B1"}'::text[] <@ (json_val_arr(json, 'name'));
```

Now my questions:

1. Is it possible to find values with a wildcard (eg. "Value*")? Something like the following (naive) approach:

   ```
   ...
   WHERE '{"Value%"}'::text[] <@ (json_val_arr(json, 'name'));
   ```
2. Is it possible to find numeric values with comparison operators (eg. >= 10)? Again, a naive and obviously wrong approach:

   ```
   ...
   WHERE '{10}'::int[] >= (json_val_arr(json, 'value'));
   ```

   I tried to create a new function returning `int[]` but that did not work.

I created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f555e/4) to illustrate my problem.

Or would it be better to use a different approach like the following working queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM data,
   json_array_elements(json) jsondata
WHERE jsondata ->> 'name' LIKE 'Value%';
```

and

```
...
WHERE cast(jsondata ->> 'value' as integer) <= 10;
```

However, for these queries, I was not able to create any index that was actually picked up by the queries.

Also, I'd like to implement all this in Postgresql 9.4 with JSONB eventually, but I think for the above questions this should not be an issue.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 12):

I know its been a while but I was just chugging on something similar (using wild cards to query json datatypes) and thought I'd share what I found.

Firstly, this was a huge point in the right direction:
http://schinckel.net/2014/05/25/querying-json-in-postgres/

The take away is that your method of exploding the json element into something else (a record-set) is the way to go. It lets you query the json elements with normal postgres stuff.

In my case:

```
#Table:test
    ID | jsonb_column
     1 | {"name": "", "value": "reserved", "expires_in": 13732}
     2 | {"name": "poop", "value": "{\"ns\":[\"Whaaat.\"]}", "expires_in": 4554} 
     3 | {"name": "dog", "value": "{\"ns\":[\"woof.\"]}", "expires_in": 4554}
```

Example Query

```
select * from test jsonb_to_recordset(x) where jsonb_column->>'name' like '%o%';

# => Returns
# 2 | {"name": "poop", "value": "{\"ns\":[\"Whaaat.\"]}", "expires_in": 4554}
```

And to answer your question about jsonb: It looks like jsonb is the better route MOST of the time. It has more methods and faster read (but slower write) times.

Sources:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html

Happy hunting!

Comment: What is the x referring to? Can't figure out how to make this query run

Comment: Not sure what the `x` is either but this worked for me: 

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people, jsonb_to_record(people.data) AS x(title text)  WHERE x.title LIKE '%Police%'"`

Assuming the `people.data` is a jsonb column and has a key called title. Note that it's expanding to a record not recordset.