# Query and order by number of matches in JSON array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, postgresql-9.4

Using JSON arrays in a `jsonb` column in Postgres 9.4 and Rails, I can set up a scope that returns all rows containing **any** elements from an array passed to the scope method - like so:

```
scope :tagged, ->(tags) {
  where(["data->'tags' ?| ARRAY[:tags]", { tags: tags }])
}
```

**I'd also like to order the results based on the number of matched elements in the array.**

I appreciate I might need to step outside the confines of ActiveRecord to do this, so a vanilla Postgres SQL answer is helpful too, but bonus points if it can be wrapped up in ActiveRecord so it can be a chain-able scope.

As requested, here's an example table. (Actual schema is far more complicated but this is all I'm concerned about.)

```
 id |               data                
----+-----------------------------------
  1 | {"tags": ["foo", "bar", "baz"]}
  2 | {"tags": ["bish", "bash", "baz"]}
  3 |
  4 | {"tags": ["foo", "foo", "foo"]}
```

The use case is to find related content based on tags. More matching tags are more relevant, hence results should be ordered by the number of matches. In Ruby I'd have a simple method like this:

```
Page.tagged(['foo', 'bish', 'bash', 'baz']).all
```

Which should return the pages in the following order: `2, 1, 4`.

Comment: The ordering part. I want to order the results based on the number of matches.

Comment: cool..... let me think.

Comment: It would help if you provided your table definition, some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I've added a few more details (although your answer below already looks great).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your arrays contain only [primitive values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29947194/939860), nested documents would be more complicated.

### Query

Unnest the JSON arrays of found rows with [`jsonb_array_elements_text()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) in a `LATERAL` join and count matches:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT *
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  data->'tags' ?| ARRAY['foo', 'bar']
   ) t
, LATERAL (
   SELECT count(*) AS ct
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements_text(t.data->'tags') a(elem)
   WHERE  elem = ANY (ARRAY['foo', 'bar'])  -- same array parameter
   ) ct
ORDER  BY ct.ct DESC;  -- more expressions to break ties?
```

Alternative with [**`INSTERSECT`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html). It's one of the rare occasions that we can make use of this basic SQL feature:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT *
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  data->'tags' ?| '{foo, bar}'::text[]  -- alt. syntax w. array
   ) t
, LATERAL (
   SELECT count(*) AS ct
   FROM  (
      SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(t.data->'tags')
      INTERSECT ALL
      SELECT * FROM unnest('{foo, bar}'::text[])  -- same array literal
      ) i
   ) ct
ORDER  BY ct.ct DESC;
```

Note a **subtle difference**: This *consumes* each element when matched, so it does not count unmatched duplicates in `data->'tags'` like the first variant does. *For details see the demo below.*

Also demonstrating an alternative way to pass the array parameter: as array literal: `'{foo, bar}'`. This may be simpler to handle for *some* clients:

- [PostgreSQL: Issue with passing array to procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963380/postgresql-issue-with-passing-array-to-procedure/27963713#27963713)

Or you could create a server side search function taking a `VARIADIC` parameter and pass a variable number of plain `text` values:

- [Passing multiple values in single parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109037/passing-multiple-values-in-single-parameter/28115702#28115702)

Related:

- [Check if key exists in a JSON with PL/pgSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677057/check-if-key-exists-in-a-json-with-pl-pgsql/30733758#30733758)

#### Index

Be sure to have a **functional GIN index** to support the [`jsonb` existence operator **`?|`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE):

```sql
CREATE INDEX tbl_dat_gin ON tbl USING gin (data->'tags');
```

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)
- [What's the proper index for querying structures in arrays in Postgres jsonb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499266/whats-the-proper-index-for-querying-structures-in-arrays-in-postgres-jsonb/27708358#27708358)

### Nuances with duplicates

Clarification as per [request in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30557511/query-and-order-by-number-of-matches-in-json-array/31502719?noredirect=1#comment50969384_31502719). Say, we have a JSON array with *two* duplicated tags (4 total):

```sql
jsonb '{"tags": ["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar"]}'
```

And search with an SQL array parameter including *both* tags, *one* of them duplicated (3 total):

```sql
'{foo, bar, foo}'::text[]
```

Consider the results of this demo:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT jsonb '{"tags":["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar"]}') t(data)

, LATERAL (
   SELECT count(*) AS ct
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements_text(t.data->'tags') e
   WHERE  e = ANY ('{foo, bar, foo}'::text[])
   ) ct

, LATERAL (
   SELECT count(*) AS ct_intsct_all
   FROM  (
      SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(t.data->'tags')
      INTERSECT ALL
      SELECT * FROM unnest('{foo, bar, foo}'::text[])
      ) i
   ) ct_intsct_all

, LATERAL (
   SELECT count(DISTINCT e) AS ct_dist
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements_text(t.data->'tags') e
   WHERE  e = ANY ('{foo, bar, foo}'::text[])
   ) ct_dist

, LATERAL (
   SELECT count(*) AS ct_intsct
   FROM  (
      SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(t.data->'tags')
      INTERSECT
      SELECT * FROM unnest('{foo, bar, foo}'::text[])
      ) i
   ) ct_intsct;
```

Result:

```sql
data                                     | ct | ct_intsct_all | ct_dist | ct_intsct
-----------------------------------------+----+---------------+---------+----------
'{"tags": ["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar"]}' | 4  | 3             | 2       | 2
```

Comparing elements in the JSON array to elements in the array parameter:

- **4** tags match any of the search elements: **`ct`**.
- **3** tags in the set *intersect* (can be matched element-to-element): **`ct_intsct_all`**.
- **2** *distinct* matching tags can be identified: **`ct_dist`** or **`ct_intsct`**.

If you don't have dupes or if you don't care to exclude them, use one of the first two techniques. The other two are a bit slower (besides the different result), because they have to check for dupes.

Comment: This looks great, thank you. Will dig deeper and have a play over the weekend, and let you know how I get on.

Comment: One of the most insightful answers I've seen. I learned tons from your post. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting details of my solution in Ruby, in case it's useful to anyone tackling the same issue.

In the end I decided a scope isn't appropriate as the method will return the an array of objects (not a chainable `ActiveRecord::Relation`), so I've written a class method and have provided a way to pass a chained scope to it through a block:

```
def self.with_any_tags(tags, &block)
  composed_scope = (
    block_given? ? yield : all
  ).where(["data->'tags' ?| ARRAY[:tags]", { tags: tags }])

  t   = Arel::Table.new('t',  ActiveRecord::Base)
  ct  = Arel::Table.new('ct', ActiveRecord::Base)

  arr_sql = Arel.sql "ARRAY[#{ tags.map { |t| Arel::Nodes::Quoted.new(t).to_sql }.join(', ') }]"
  any_tags_func = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('ANY', [arr_sql])

  lateral = ct
    .project(Arel.sql('e').count(true).as('ct'))
    .from(Arel.sql "jsonb_array_elements_text(t.data->'tags') e")
    .where(Arel::Nodes::Equality.new Arel.sql('e'), any_tags_func)

  query = t
    .project(t[Arel.star])
    .from(composed_scope.as('t'))
    .join(Arel.sql ", LATERAL (#{ lateral.to_sql }) ct")
    .order(ct[:ct].desc)

  find_by_sql query.to_sql
end
```

This can be used like so:

```
Page.with_any_tags(['foo', 'bar'])

# SELECT "t".*
# FROM (
#   SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages"
#   WHERE data->'tags' ?| ARRAY['foo','bar']
#   ) t,
# LATERAL (
#   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e) AS ct
#   FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(t.data->'tags') e
#   WHERE e = ANY(ARRAY['foo', 'bar'])
#   ) ct
# ORDER BY "ct"."ct" DESC

Page.with_any_tags(['foo', 'bar']) do
  Page.published
end

# SELECT "t".*
# FROM (
#   SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages"
#   WHERE pages.published_at <= '2015-07-19 15:11:59.997134'
#   AND pages.deleted_at IS NULL
#   AND data->'tags' ?| ARRAY['foo','bar']
#   ) t,
# LATERAL (
#   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e) AS ct
#   FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(t.data->'tags') e
#   WHERE e = ANY(ARRAY['foo', 'bar'])
#   ) ct
# ORDER BY "ct"."ct" DESC
```

Comment: Where `DISTINCT` in `COUNT(DISTINCT e)` is only relevant if the JSON array *can* hold duplicates which shall not be counted.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I don't fully understand your comment. Can you please clarify the difference between your second solution (using `INTERSECT ALL`), the variant just using `INTERSECT`, and my solution using `COUNT(DISTINCT e)`. There seems to be a few nuances here I'm not getting. I only used DISTINCT as it involved less code gymnastics using Ruby's `arel`.

Comment: I added a demo to my answer to illustrate the differences.