# Check if key exists in a JSON with PL/pgSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, plpgsql, json

I'm trying to check if a key exists in a JSON sent as parameter in a PL/pgSQL function.

Here is the function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION sp_update_user(user_info json) RETURNS json
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
    BEGIN
    PERFORM user_info->>'lastname';
    IF FOUND
    THEN
      UPDATE users SET lastname = user_info->>'lastname' WHERE id = sp_update_user.user_id;
    END IF;

    PERFORM user_info->>'firstname';
    IF FOUND
    THEN
      UPDATE users SET firstname = user_info->>'firstname' WHERE id = sp_update_user.user_id;
    END IF;

    RETURN row_to_json(row) FROM (SELECT true AS success) row;
END;$$;
```

I tried with the `PERFORM`-clause, but even if the json key does not exists, the statements in the `IF FOUND` clause are executed.

I tried `PERFORM user_info->>'firstname' INTO myvar;` in order to check the variable content but it triggers an error `ERROR:  query "SELECT user_info->>'firstname' INTO myvar" is not a SELECT`.

How can I check if a json key exists in a JSON with PL/pgSQL?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You already found that you can test the expression `user_info->>'username'` for NULL. But your function is still **very inefficient**. And there are still **ambiguities**.

#### Better solution in Postgres 9.3

It is expensive to update a row repeatedly for multiple columns. Postgres writes a new row version for every update. Use a *single* `UPDATE` if at all possible:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_update_user(_user_id int, _user_info json)
  RETURNS json AS
$func$
BEGIN
   UPDATE users u
   SET    firstname = COALESCE(_user_info->>'firstname', u.firstname)
        , lastname  = COALESCE(_user_info->>'lastname' , u.lastname)
   WHERE  id = sp_update_user._user_id
   AND   ((_user_info->>'firstname') IS NOT NULL OR
          (_user_info->>'lastname')  IS NOT NULL);

   IF FOUND THEN
      RETURN '{"success":true}'::json;
   ELSE
      RETURN '{"success":false}'::json;
   END IF;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT sp_update_user(123, '{"firstname": "jon", "lastname": "doe"}')
```

- This is substantially faster for multiple columns, since only a single `UPDATE` (at most) is executed. If the `WHERE` clause doesn't evaluate to `true`, no update happens at all and you get `'{"success":false}'` as result.
- If sometimes the values in the table are already what they are being changed to, another optimization is possible. Consider the last paragraph of this related answer:

  - [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)
- The variable / parameter `user_id` is missing in your original.
- There is still a corner case **ambiguity**. If the element exists and is set to **JSON `null`**, you also get an SQL `NULL` as result. Consider:

  ```
  SELECT ('{"b": null}'::json->>'b') IS NULL AS b_is_null
       , ('{"c": 2}'::json->>'b')    IS NULL AS b_missing;
  ```
- Not sure why you use data type `json` as return type, I just kept that. But if the function does not update, you cannot be sure why you get `false`. There might be no row with the given `id`, the key names `'firstname'` and `'lastname'` could be missing - or be `null` ...

### Superior solution in Postgres 9.4

There is a **clean** and simple solution in Postgres **9.4** with **`jsonb`** with the [**`?` "existence" operator**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) - which can even use an index for bigger tables (not relevant in your function):

```
SELECT ('{"b": null}'::jsonb ? 'b') AS b_is_null
     , ('{"c": 2}'::jsonb ? 'b')    AS b_missing;
```

And the [`?|` and `?&` variants](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) to check for multiple keys at once.
So we can implement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_update_user(_user_id int, _user_info jsonb)
  RETURNS jsonb AS
$func$
BEGIN
   UPDATE users u
   SET    firstname = CASE WHEN _user_info ? 'firstname' THEN _user_info->>'firstname' ELSE u.firstname END
        , lastname  = CASE WHEN _user_info ? 'lastname'  THEN _user_info->>'lastname'  ELSE u.lastname  END
   WHERE  id = sp_update_user._user_id
   AND    _user_info ?| '{firstname,lastname}';

   IF FOUND THEN
      RETURN '{"success":true}'::jsonb;
   ELSE
      RETURN '{"success":false}'::jsonb;
   END IF;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

These calls work as expected now:

```
SELECT sp_update_user(123, '{"firstname": null, "lastname": "doe1"}'::jsonb);
SELECT sp_update_user(123, '{"firstname": "doris"}'::jsonb);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, it is way much better than anything I've found before ! I'm seriously considering an update to Postgres 9.4...

Comment: @DeadEye: if you have to deal with JSON a lot that's an excellent idea.

Answer (score 2):

The "json_object_keys" function can be a solution.

You can select the result of a query that uses this function into a declared variable and then check if your variable is null. Here is an example:

```
DECLARE
test character varying;
BEGIN
    SELECT a INTO test FROM json_object_keys(user_info) a WHERE a = 'lastname';
    IF (test IS NOT NULL) THEN
        --SUCESSS
    ELSE
        --FAIL
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: This solution is pretty fine ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Found a simpler solution that checks if the json key have a value.

```
IF (user_info->>'username') IS NOT NULL
THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'username';
      UPDATE users SET username = user_info->>'username' WHERE id = sp_update_user.user_id;
END IF;
```

This checks if the key 'username' in the json have a volume other than NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check if a JSON key exists is with `json_extract_path()`. Here's an example use:

```
SELECT permit_id FROM building_permits WHERE
json_extract_path(containing_boundaries, 'neighborhood') IS NULL
```

This looks for a property in your JSON object ("containing_boundaries") called "neighborhood". If the property does not exist, it returns NULL.