# postgres: why does this GIN index not used for this "object in array" query

Tags: arrays, postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I am trying to index a JSONB column that contains array of objects :

```
create table tmp_t (a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,o jsonb);

insert into tmp_t (a,o)  values(1, '[{"frame": 1, "accession": "NM_001184642.1"}]');
insert into tmp_t (a,o)  values (2, '[{"frame": 3, "accession": "NM_001178208.1"}]');

CREATE INDEX idx_tmp_t ON tmp_t USING gin (o);
```

EXPLAIN tells me the following query does not use the index :

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT * from tmp_t v where v.o @> '[{"accession": "NM_001178208.1"}]';
```

explain result:

```
QUERY PLAN
Seq Scan on tmp_t v  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=1 width=36)
  Filter: (o @> '[{""accession"": ""NM_001178208.1""}]'::jsonb)
```

My setup seems identical to the one given in answer to this question :

[Using indexes in json array in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945205/using-indexes-in-json-array-in-postgresql/29947194#29947194)

I have created the example table in the question, and the index *does* get used :

```
"QUERY PLAN"
"Bitmap Heap Scan on tracks  (cost=16.01..20.02 rows=1 width=36)"
"  Recheck Cond: (artists @> '[{""z"": 2}]'::jsonb)"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tracks_artists_gin_idx  (cost=0.00..16.01 rows=1 width=0)"
"        Index Cond: (artists @> '[{""z"": 2}]'::jsonb)"
```

Comment: For only two rows, an index will never be used.

Answer (score 12):

Actually the index is used, [just use larger test data.](http://rextester.com/QTIE46498)

The planner can choose different plans depending on the data. It often happens that the planner doesn't use an index on a dataset with a small number of rows and starts using it when amount of data grows.

Comment: Thanks. I can see that the index get used  on rextester.com, it still doesn't on my 9.4.x postgres instance, perhaps it's time I upgrade, although I can't find in the release notes which version does the upgrade...

Comment: It doesn't depend on the version of the server. See the edited answer.

Comment: hmm, I tried your example with 1,000,000 rows, and still the index was not used, I wonder how many rows is "sufficient" to cause index usage....

Comment: I've tested it on 9.5 windows and 9.4 ubuntu with the results like on rextester. You might be interested in [How do I force Postgres to use a particular index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309786/how-do-i-force-postgres-to-use-a-particular-index) and [Why is my index not being used?](https://www.depesz.com/2010/09/09/why-is-my-index-not-being-used/).

Comment: @MaxL.: it's not only the total number of rows but also how many rows the optimizer expects to be removed by the where condition. If the condition only removes 100 rows from a million rows, the index won't help. If the condition only leaves a 1000 rows from that million then the index should be used