# Speed up range test for key values nested in jsonb array of objects

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

Suppose I have the following `parents` table:

```sql
create table parents (
  id       integer not null constraint parents_pkey primary key,
  name     text    not null,
  children jsonb   not null
);
```

Where `children` is a **json array** of the following structure:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "child1",
        "age": 10
    }, 
    {
        "name": "child2",
        "age": 12
    } 
]
```

And I need, for example, to get all parents that have children with age between 10 and 12.

I create the following query:

```sql
select distinct
  p.*
from
  parents p, jsonb_array_elements(p.children) c
where
  (c->>'age')::int between 10 and 12;
```

It works well but very slowly when the table `parents` is big (for example 1M records). I tried to use 'gin' index on `children` field but this did not help.

So is there a way to speed up such queries? Or maybe there is another solution to make queries/indexes against **fields** in the **nested json arrays**?

**Query plan**:

```
Unique  (cost=1793091.18..1803091.18 rows=1000000 width=306) (actual time=4070.866..5106.998 rows=399947 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=1793091.18..1795591.18 rows=1000000 width=306) (actual time=4070.864..4836.241 rows=497313 loops=1)
        Sort Key: p.id, p.children, p.name
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 186040kB
        ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..1406321.34 rows=1000000 width=306) (actual time=0.892..1354.147 rows=497313 loops=1)
              Workers Planned: 2
              Workers Launched: 2
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..1305321.34 rows=416667 width=306) (actual time=0.162..1794.134 rows=165771 loops=3)
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on parents p  (cost=0.00..51153.67 rows=416667 width=306) (actual time=0.075..239.786 rows=333333 loops=3)
                    ->  Function Scan on jsonb_array_elements c  (cost=0.00..3.00 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1000000)
                          Filter: ((((value ->> 'age'::text))::integer >= 10) AND (((value ->> 'age'::text))::integer <= 12))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 3
Planning time: 0.218 ms
Execution time: 5140.277 ms
```

Comment: The only way to radically speed up querying these values is to normalize the model. `Children` are crying to be a table.

Comment: @klin I know. It is a table now, but it want be a json array ))

Comment: Oh no, don't do it to them!

Comment: I, too, think the poor children deserve their own table. You can always add a `VIEW` returning the JSON representation. Should be fast and simple. But there *are* ways to help the poor children in the crowded `jsonb` value, too ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter You are giving them the hope! Children love their parents very much, let's help them stay with their parents! )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A first immediate measure would be to make the query you have a bit faster:

```
SELECT *
FROM   parents p
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM jsonb_array_elements(p.children) c
   WHERE (c->>'age')::int BETWEEN 10 AND 12
   );
```

The `EXISTS` semi-join avoids duplication of rows in the intermediate table when multiple array objects match - and the need for `DISTINCT ON` in the outer query. But that's only mildly faster, yet.

The core problem is that you want to test for a *range of integer values*, while [existing `jsonb` operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) do not provide such functionality.

There are various ways around this. Not knowing any of this, here is a "smart" solution that solves the given example. The trick is to split the range to distinct values and use the `jsonb` containment operator `@>`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   parents p
WHERE (p.children @> '[{"age": 10}]'
OR     p.children @> '[{"age": 11}]'
OR     p.children @> '[{"age": 12}]');
```

Supported by a `jsonb_path_ops` GIN index:

```
CREATE INDEX parents_children_gin_idx ON parents USING gin (children jsonb_path_ops);
```

But if your ranges span more than a hand full of integer values, you'll need something more generic. As *always*, the best solution depends on the complete situation: Data distribution, value frequencies, typical ranges in queries, NULL values possible?, row size, read/write patterns, does *every* `jsonb` value have one or more matching `age` key? ...

Related answer with specialized, very fast index:

- [Search for nested values in jsonb array with greater operator](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202739/search-for-nested-values-in-jsonb-array-with-greater-operator)

Related:

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)
- [Using indexes in json array in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945205/using-indexes-in-json-array-in-postgresql/29947194#29947194)

Comment: Thank you very mach Erwin, it's brilliantly as always! Your solution with 'exists' gave more than 2 times acceleration according to the query plan, but the real query with 'limit 20' have got the data in only 45 ms - and this is on my slow home computer!

Comment: @Cepr0: `LIMIT` is a game changer and can generally favor completely different query plans. The fact that Postgres has no real statistics for nested values *inside* a `jsonb` column can lead to suboptimal query plans for non-standard distributions. Depending on the complete situation there are still faster solutions for the query without `LIMIT`, too ...

Comment: I do not have a concrete example now - we are considering the possibility to simplify the structure of the database. We are working with the Spring/Hibernate/PostgreSQL stack to build REST services and are thinking to move all dependent (embedded) entities to the table of the main/parent entity (aggregate root) in order to optimize/simplify the retrieving data with pagination. But without loss of functionality (data filtering on nested entities). If you can give any suggestion, I will be very grateful!

Comment: @Cepr0: Not sure how to advise there. This related answer might be useful for pagination: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34291099/939860. Good luck with the migration!

Comment: @Cepr0: you may be interested in the added link to a related answer.

Comment: Thank you, Erwin, again! I seen almost all your significant answers on this topic.. Your help is very important for us!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try this way (this is from my experience).

```
WITH t AS (SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements(children) as child_data FROM parents)
SELECT *  
  FROM parents 
 WHERE id IN (
              SELECT id
                FROM t
               WHERE (child_data->>'age')::int between 10 and 12
           )
```

Hopefully it works.

Comment: Sorry, but your query is slowly than mine... ((