# Existance of key in JSON array in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, psql

I've got a problem that I can't quite figure out.

Let's say I have a column called movies that look like this (jsonb):

```
[{"title": "Pulp Fiction"}, {"tiitle": "Rambo"}]
```

is there a way to find rows where movies has an object with the key tiitle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Postgres 9.4:

```
ds=# CREATE TABLE yourtable (movie jsonb);
CREATE TABLE
ds=# \d+ yourtable 
                      Table "public.yourtable"
 Column | Type  | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------+-------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 movie  | jsonb |           | extended |              | 

ds=# INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES ('[{"title": "Pulp Fiction"}, {"tiitle": "Rambo"}]');
INSERT 0 1

ds=# SELECT * FROM yourtable yt,jsonb_array_elements(yt.movies) AS movie
WHERE movie ? 'tiitle';
```

SO has a lot of [good resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706) together with Postgres [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html).