# Query on Postgres JSON array field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I am trying to query a certain value in a Postgres database. I have a field named `groups` in the `users` table that can be represented in either of these ways:

1.

```
groups: {"data"=>[{"serie"=>5, "year"=>3, "specialization"=>"Matematica", "management_id"=>1, "group_number"=>2}, {"serie"=>5, "year"=>3, "specialization"=>"Matematica", "management_id"=>1, "group_number"=>2}]}
```

2.

```
groups: [{"serie"=>5, "year"=>3, "specialization"=>"Matematica", "management_id"=>1, "group_number"=>2}, {"serie"=>5, "year"=>3, "specialization"=>"Matematica", "management_id"=>1, "group_number"=>2}]
```

I am fine with either of this representations. However I just can't seem to find out how to get all the users that are in serie 5 let's say. I tried multiple queries along the lines of:

```
@users = User.where("groups ->> 'data' @>  ?", {serie: 5})
@users = User.where("groups -> 'data' @>  '?'", {serie: 5})
@users = User.where("groups ->> 'data' ->> 'serie' = ?", 5)
```

And many other attempts, some more stupid than others (see above). How would I do it?

I have been able to determine that:

```
select groups -> 'data' ->> 'serie' from users;  
ERROR: cannot extract field from a non-object.
```

However the following query works:

```
select json_array_elements(groups -> 'data') ->> 'serie' from users;
```

I think I am not properly delivering the data in the column. The hash I am providing to create is:

```
pry(#<Overrides::RegistrationsController>)> @response['data']['user']
=> {"last_name"=>"Doe1",
 "first_name"=>"John1",
 "email"=>"c0f45@example.com",
 "groups"=>
  {"data"=>
    [{"serie"=>5, "year"=>3, "specialization"=>"Matematica", "management_id"=>1, "group_number"=>2}, {"serie"=>5, "year"=>3, "specialization"=>"Matematica", "management_id"=>1, "group_number"=>2}]}}
```

Before saving the resource looks like this:

```
pry(#<Overrides::RegistrationsController>)> @resource
=> #<User id: nil, provider: "email", uid: "", first_name: "John1", last_name: "Doe1", email: "c0f45@example.com", role: "Student", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, groups: {"data"=>[{"serie"=>5, "year"=>3, "specialization"=>"Matematica", "management_id"=>1, "group_number"=>2}, {"serie"=>5, "year"=>3, "specialization"=>"Matematica", "management_id"=>1, "group_number"=>2}]}>
```

Comment: Please *always* declare your version of Postgres. (`SELECT version();`) Is it current 9.6? And the exact table definition should be given too. `json` or `jsonb` makes a difference. *Also*, please define *"users that are in serie 5"*. Your example shows multiple array elements, where all have the same value `5` for the key `serie`. Yre you looking for rows with at least one match? Or must all array elements match?

Comment: At least one match :D

Comment: You can find different types of queries [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mankind/1802dbb64fc24be33d434d593afd6221/raw/37293e4ba5d3d19c7e25dc8da84402b18fdc914d/rails-jsonb-queries)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### Assumptions

- Postgres **9.4 or later**.
- *"get all the users that are in serie 5"* is supposed to mean:
  *"with at least one array element that contains `{"serie": 5}`. There may be others."*
- Working with your first, shorter data format. No redundant 'data' key.

#### Short answer

Use **`jsonb`** instead of `json` and this just works:

```
User.where("groups @> ?", '[{"serie": 5}]')
```

Note the square brackets to make the right-hand operand a JSON *array*.

#### Why?

The prominent misunderstanding here: [data type **`json`** is not the same as  **`jsonb`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html).

You didn't declare the actual table definition, but you later commented `json` and there is a hint in the question:

> ```
> select json_array_elements(groups -> 'data') ->> 'serie' from users;
> ```

`json_array_elements()` only works for `json`, would have to be `jsonb_array_elements()` for `jsonb`. But you try to use the [**`jsonb` operator `@>`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) which is not defined for `json`:

> ```
> groups -> 'data' @>  '?'
> ```

The [operator `->`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) returns the same type as the left-hand input. But `@>` is only defined for `jsonb`, not for `json`.

Then you try to use the operator `@>` for `text` as left-hand operand. **Not possible either**:

> ```
> groups ->> 'data' @>  ?
> ```

There are variants of the operator `@>` for various types (incl. Postgres arrays), but not for `text` and not for `json`.

So the answer is: Use `jsonb` instead of `json`. This allows to use very **efficient indexes**, too:

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)

### SQL Demos

#### `json`

For data type `json` you could use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   users u
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM json_array_elements(u.groups) elem 
   WHERE  elem ->> 'serie' = '5'
   );
```

#### `jsonb`

After altering the column type to `jsonb`:

```
ALTER TABLE users ALTER column groups TYPE jsonb;
```

Simply:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   users
WHERE  groups @> '[{"serie": 5}]';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/g7l8vO8M)

Comment: You are perfectly right. I've read some tutorials on working with json fields in postgres. But .. obviously they were working with jsonb whilst i was using json. My postgres version was 9.3 and didn't want to upgrade to 9.4 as i thought i could use the operators for jsonb. All in all, thank you very much!! and for the explanations

Comment: How would you use a variable instead of a string literal as the query? (For example, substituting a variable for "serie")

Comment: @supersaidso: Well, `'[{"serie": 5}]'` can be passed as variable (type `jsonb`), or as string literal. Or you can build the jsonb value dynamically. To just set the *value*: `... WHERE groups @> jsonb_set('[{"serie": 5}]'::jsonb, '{0,serie}', '5')`. Or use an SQL/JSON path expression. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69731065/939860 or https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/196635/3684

Answer (score 1):

JSON filtering in Rails

```rb
Event.create(payload: [{ "name": 'Jack', "age": 12 },
                       { "name": 'John', "age": 13 },
                       { "name": 'Dohn', "age": 24 }])
```

```rb
Event.where('payload @> ?', '[{"age": 12}]')
# You can also filter by name key
Event.where('payload @> ?', '[{"name": "John"}]')
# You can also filter by {"name":"Jack", "age":12}
Event.where('payload @> ?', {"name":"Jack", "age":12}.to_json)
```

You can find more about this [here](https://www.cstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails/how-to-query-postgresqls-json-fields-from-rails)