# How to query a PostgreSQL jsonb array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

In my `Car` model I have an array of `Component`s stored in a PostgreSQL JSONB field.

A record looks like

```
id: 1
name: DeLorean
components: [{"name": "engine", "maker": "doc", "scope": "system"}, 
             {"name": "transmission", "maker": "doc", "scope": "subsystem"}]
```

How can I query the database to fetch only the `Car`s having a `Component` with `name` = `engine` and `maker` = `doc`?

I have tried different things, among which the following but all without success.

```
Car.where('components @> ?', {name: 'engine', maker: 'doc'}.to_json)
```

Comment: if you look at the docs https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json-and-jsonb, it looks like you have to do something like: `Car.where("components->>'name' = ? AND components->>'maker' = ?", 'engine', 'doc')`.

Comment: Thanks, but I get back `#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`.

Comment: does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40702813/query-on-postgres-json-array-field-in-rails help ?

Comment: It helps indeed. `Car.where('components @> ?', '[{"name": "engine", "maker": "doc" }]')`