# How to query jsonb array field in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

How to use active record to query an array of jsonb objects

Schema

```
 create_table "routes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "state"
    t.text "address"
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.jsonb "travel_routes", array: true
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_routes_on_user_id"
  end
```

Rails Console

```
travel_routes: [{"to"=>"Yaba Lagos", "fee"=>5000}, {"to"=>"Lagos Iyanapaja", "fee"=>3000}]
```

Comment: What you want to query against this JSONB column?

Comment: Yes I want to query against the JSONB column using Active Record

Comment: Are you sure PostgreSQL does not support jsonb Array, because it is accepting my inputs very fine, just querying the data that is a bit of a headache. 

How would I query a json[] array, any examples you could show me based on the data above.

Answer (score 14):

This was answered well in this SO post:

[Query on Postgres JSON array field in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40702813/query-on-postgres-json-array-field-in-rails)

For the question in this post, this should work to find where "to" = "Yaba Lagos":

```
Route.where('travel_routes @> ?', '[{"to": "Yaba Lagos"}]')
```

Answer (score 8):

It also works this way:

```rb
Route.where('travel_routes @> ?', [{to: "Yaba Lagos"}].to_json)
```