# PostgreSQL indexing JSONB array

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, indexing, jsonb

Here is my json

```
jsondata
------------------------------------
{"key1": 1, "keyset": [10, 20, 30]}
{"key1": 1, "keyset": [10, 20]}
{"key1": 1, "keyset": [30]}
{"key1": 1 }
{"key1": 1, "key2": 1}
```

I tried creating index `keyset` for above example 
1st index using btree

```
CREATE INDEX test_keyset ON test_table (jsondata->'keyset');
```

2nd index using gin

```
CREATE INDEX test_keyset ON test_table USING GIN(jsondata->'keyset');
```

and query to select `keyset` value 10,

```
SELECT jsondata
FROM test
   JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements_text(jsondata->'keyset') a(v)
      ON TRUE
WHERE a.v::integer = 10;
```

but it is doing sequential scan(checking all rows), can anyone suggest me about which indexing method is correct(btree or gin) and efficient way of getting data from json using indexing for above example, I'm new to postgres

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18405706/3270427

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use gin index on the expression `jsondata->'keyset'`:

```
create index test_keyset on test using gin((jsondata->'keyset'));
```

You should use the expression in your queries in conjunction with the `@>` operator:

```
select jsondata
from test
where jsondata->'keyset' @> '10'

              jsondata               
-------------------------------------
 {"key1": 1, "keyset": [10, 20, 30]}
 {"key1": 1, "keyset": [10, 20]}
(2 rows)
```

Test if the planner can use the index:

```
set enable_seqscan to off;

explain analyse
select jsondata
from test
where jsondata->'keyset' @> '10'

                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on test  (cost=8.00..12.02 rows=1 width=55) (actual time=0.024..0.025 rows=2 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((jsondata -> 'keyset'::text) @> '10'::jsonb)
   Heap Blocks: exact=1
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_keyset  (cost=0.00..8.00 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=2 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((jsondata -> 'keyset'::text) @> '10'::jsonb)
 Planning time: 0.576 ms
 Execution time: 0.066 ms
(7 rows)
```