# Deep search within jsonb field PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

A sample of my data looks something like this:

```
{"city": "NY", 
"skills": [
{"soft_skills": "Analysis"},
{"soft_skills": "Procrastination"},
{"soft_skills": "Presentation"}
],
"areas_of_training": [
{"areas of training": "Visio"},
{"areas of training": "Office"}, 
{"areas of training": "Risk Assesment"}
]}
```

I would like to run a query to find users with soft_skills `Analysis` and maybe run another one to find users whose area of training is `Visio` and `Risk Assesment`

My column type is `jsonb`. How can I implement a search query on these deeply nested objects? A query on level one for city works using `SELECT * FROM mydata WHERE content::json->>'city'='NY';`

How can I also run a match using the LIKE keyword or string matching for deeply nested values?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1)

```
SELECT * FROM mydata
WHERE content->'skills' @> '[{"soft_skills": "Analysis"}]';
```

2)

```
SELECT * FROM mydata
WHERE content->'areas_of_training' @> '[{"areas of training": "Visio"},{"areas of training": "Risk Assesment"}]';
```

[About JSON(B) operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

PS: And be ready for extremely slow queries. I highly recommend to think about [data normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

---

Update for `LIKE`

For your example data it could be:

```
SELECT * FROM mydata
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM jsonb_array_elements(content->'areas_of_training') as a
  WHERE a->>'areas of training' ilike '%vi%');
```

But query highly depending on the actual JSON structure.

Comment: I have edited the question to include possibility of using the LIKE keyword or string matching.

Comment: I would have liked to have a better normalized structure but this data is coming from some dynamic form generator hence the need to find a way round its result structure.

Comment: Consider an automated import of the data to a normalized table(s).

Comment: @Churchill Ok, got it.

Comment: With regards to the comment on slow performance, could that be addressed with a GIN index? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18405706/494635

Answer (score 6):

Use `json_array_elements()` to get values of nested elements, examples:

```
select d.*
from mydata d,
json_array_elements(content->'skills')
where value->>'soft_skills' ilike '%analysis%';

select d.*
from mydata d,
json_array_elements(content->'areas_of_training')
where value->>'areas of training' ~* 'visio|office';
```

It is possible that the query yields duplicate rows, so it is reasonable to use `select distinct on (id)`, where `id` is a primary key.

Note that the function `json_array_elements()` is costly and you cannot use indexes in contrary to Abelisto's solution. However you have to use it if you want to have an access to values of nested json elements.

Comment: This also works though I had to change my column data type to json and not jsonb for the json_array_elements to work without casting using `::`

Comment: If the column is `jsonb` just use `jsonb_array_elements()`.