# Postgres: how to do an index on a jsonb[] column?

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres is it possible to create an index on a `jsonb[]` column?

I have a table that contains a set of `jsonb[]` array, and each json in table  A has a reference to another table B.

I want to have the count of element B in A when I select B.

I do something like :

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    (SELECT count(*) 
     FROM A, unnest(jsons) json 
     WHERE json->>'id' = B.id) 
FROM B
```

That works but it is very slow :( !

Comment: Sorry by: Yhak work but very slow 
I wanted to write That work but very slow

Comment: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Comment: did you try to create the index using these instructions https://stackoverflow.com/a/18405706/1265980 ? what error did you get?

Comment: Yes I have this error:
data type jsonb[] has no default operator class for access method "gin"