# Most efficient way to query data nested deep in JSON arrays?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, database-design, jsonb, postgresql-performance

Currently I'm writing queries against a JSONB table with 8 million+ rows.  How can I query from the `parent` and the `friends` objects in the most efficient manner possible?

Query (Postgres 9.6):

```
select distinct id, data->>'_id' jsonID, data->>'email' email, friends->>'name' friend_name, parent->>'name' parent
from temp t
CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(t.data->'friends') friends
CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(friends->'parent') parent
where friends ->> 'name' = 'Chan Franco'
and parent->>'name' = 'Hannah Golden'
```

Example DDL (with data): https://pastebin.com/byN7uyKx

Comment: Please put all defining information into your question. Your version of Postgres, table definition, sample value. (Lengthy test case can stay at the external site - a fiddle site like dbfiddle.uk or sqlfiddle.com would be better suited for this.)

Comment: A more efficient way would be to normalize your model. http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I'll be looking to normalize this data model!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regularly structured data would be cleaner, smaller and faster as normalized relational design.

That said, to make the setup you have *much* faster (if not as fast as a normalized design with matching indexes), add a **GIN index on the expression `data->'friends'`**:

```
 CREATE INDEX tbl_data_friends_gin_idx ON tbl USING gin ((data->'friends'));
```

Then add a matching `WHERE` clause to our query with the contains operator **`@>`**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  -- why DISTINCT ?
       id, data->>'_id' AS json_id, data->>'email' AS email
     , friends->>'name' AS friend_name, parent->>'name' AS parent
FROM   tbl t
CROSS  JOIN jsonb_array_elements(t.data->'friends') friends
CROSS  JOIN jsonb_array_elements(friends->'parent') parent
WHERE  t.data->'friends' @> '[{"name": "Chan Franco", "parent": [{"name": "Hannah Golden"}]}]'
AND    friends->>'name' = 'Chan Franco'
AND    parent ->>'name' = 'Hannah Golden';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9e35a91bf935c1c250ba8d2660e00a6e)*

The ***huge*** difference: With the help of the index, Postgres can now identify matching rows *before* unnesting each an every nested "friends" array in the whole table. Only *after* having identified matching rows in the underlying table, `jsonb_array_elements()` is called and resulting rows with qualifying array elements are kept.

Note that the search expression has to be valid JSON, matching the structure of the JSON array `data->'friends'` - including the outer brackets `[]`. But omit all key/value pairs that are not supposed to serve as filter.

Related:

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)

I avoided the table name `temp` as this is an SQL key word, that might lead to confusing errors. Using the name `tbl` instead.