# How to use an index when using jsonb_array_elements in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I have the next table structure:

`create table public.listings (id varchar(255) not null, data jsonb not null);`

And the next indexes:

`create index listings_data_index on public.listings using gin(data jsonb_ops);`

`create unique index listings_id_index on public.listings(id);`

`alter table public.listings add constraint listings_id_pk primary key(id);`

With this row:

```
id | data
1  | {"attributes": {"ccid": "123", "listings": [{"vin": "1234","body": "Sleeper", "make": "International"}, { "vin": "5678", "body": "Sleeper", "make": "International" }]}}
```

The use case needs to retrieve a specific item inside the `listings` array that matches a specific `vin`.

I am accomplishing that with the next query:

```
SELECT elems
FROM public.listings, jsonb_array_elements(data->'attributes'->'listings') elems
WHERE id = '1' AND elems->'vin' ? '1234';
```

The output is what I need:

`{"vin": "1234","body": "Sleeper", "make": "International"}`

Now I am in the phase of optimizing this query, since there will be millions of rows, and up to 100K items inside `listings` array.

When I run the explain over that query is shows this:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.01..2.53 rows=1 width=32)
  ->  Seq Scan on listings  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=32)
        Filter: ((id)::text = '1'::text)
  ->  Function Scan on jsonb_array_elements elems  (cost=0.01..1.51 rows=1 width=32)
        Filter: ((value -> 'vin'::text) ? '1234'::text)
```

I wonder what would be the right way to construct an index for that, or if I need to modify the query to another that is more efficient.

Thank you!

Comment: "*up to 100K items inside listings array.*" - you mean in *each* array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array)

Comment: How fast is it now?  How fast do you need it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: with a table as small as that, you will never see PostgreSQL use an index. You need to try with realistic amounts. Second: while PostgreSQL will happily use an index for the condition on `id`, it can never use an index for such a JSON search, no matter how you write it.