# Filter JSON values at least one key is in a given array and has a given value

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I want to run a query towards PostgreSQL where any attribute in a JSON body matching a list of attribute *names* should equal a given value.

The input: `names: ["foo", "bar"], value: 'hello'`
should render a query such as `SELECT ... WHERE data.foo = 'hello' OR data.bar = 'hello'`.

However, I want to use a single array parameter for the names, not manually expand it to `$1, $2` etc depending on the number of attribute names in the array.

I know how to bind a dynamic attribute name like this:

`query('SELECT "mytable.*" FROM "mytable" WHERE "mytable"."data"->>$1 = $2', ['foo', 'hello'])`

... and I also know how to pass an array parameter which is used to supply a set of *values* using `WHERE data.foo ANY ($1)` etc.

But, is it possible to send a single array parameter denoting a list of attribute *names* where at least one of those attributes must match the given value? Is there a function within PostgreSQL to say something like (pseudo-query to illustrate): `query('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE data-->any_of($1) = $2', [ ['foo', 'bar'], 'hello' ]`

Answer (score 1):

Close to your illustrative pseudo-query. Use this one

```sql
select * from mytable m
where exists
(
 select from json_each_text(m.data) 
 where key = any(string_to_array($1, ',')) 
   and value = $2
)
```

with these arguments (the keys' list shaped as a character-separated string)

```
['foo,bar', 'hello']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make it work with a [SQL/JSON path expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl t
WHERE  data @? '$.keyvalue() ? (@."key" like_regex "foo|bar") ? (@."value" == "hello")';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8gFv3lT-)

The "list of attribute names" enters as regex expression with branches into the expression (`"foo|bar"`).

I find path expressions comparatively hard to formulate. The beauty of it, though: they can use a GIN **index**, even the kind with `jsonb_path_ops` operator class, which is more specialized, but also smaller and faster. Should make selective queries on big tables *much* faster.

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_data_pathops_idx ON tbl USING gin (data jsonb_path_ops)
```

Related:

- [Find rows containing a key in a JSONB array of records](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/196635/3684)
- [How to sum the values ​of a json column filtered with regex?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/274276/3684)
- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array)