# Test given IDs for existence in any row of a JSON column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonpath, postgresql-performance

In my Postgres 13.10 database, I have a table `menus` with a JSON column named `dishes`. This column contains values in the following format:

```json
{
    "desserts": [
        {"id": 1, "name": "chocolate cake"},
        {"id": 2, "name": "banana split"}
    ],
    "appetizers": [
        {"id": 3, "name": "nachos"},
        {"id": 4, "name": "mozzarella sticks"},
        {"id": 5, "name": "buffalo wings"}
    ]
}
```

The data type is `json`, but I do have the option of changing it to `jsonb`, if that would help with query performance.

Given a list of appetizer IDs (for example, 3 and 5), I need to determine which IDs are referenced by at least one row in this table.

How can I write a query to do this?

(Of course, this is a contrived example.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming **`jsonb`**. (Would not scale well for plain `json`).
To make it **fast**, use [SQL/JSON path functionality](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) added with **Postgres 12**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   unnest ('{3,5}'::int[]) i(id)
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM menus
   WHERE  dishes @? format('$.*[*].id ? (@ == %s)', i.id)::jsonpath
   );
```

This searches the key "id" in all arrays nested in top-level objects of `menus.dishes`. Or restrict to the top-level key "appetizers":

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   unnest ('{3,5}'::int[]) i(id)
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM menus
   WHERE  dishes @? format('$.appetizers[*].id ? (@ == %s)', i.id)::jsonpath
   );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qQCRgUwV)

Be sure to have a GIN index on `menus(dishes)`. Ideally a `jsonb_path_ops` index:

```
CREATE INDEX menus_dishes ON menus USING gin (dishes jsonb_path_ops);
```

The **main feature** is to build a `jsonpath` expression off unnested IDs dynamically. This way it works for any number of input IDs, any number of top-level objects in the JSON documents, and any number of nested array items - while still using above index.

Related:

- [Filter JSON values at least one key is in a given array and has a given value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76306220/filter-json-values-at-least-one-key-is-in-a-given-array-and-has-a-given-value/76310399#76310399)

###### Aside

Have you considered making an actual **relational** DB out of your JSON documents? Keyword ["database normalization"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Would make queries like this a whole lot simpler and faster.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't describe how you want the list to be provided.  Here I'm providing it as a VALUES construct.

You can use the `@>` containment test, but will need to cast the data to JSONB (or just store it that way in the first place) in order to use that.  The "at least one row" suggests use of the `exists` construct.

```
select t,
  exists (select 1 from menus where dishes::jsonb @> jsonb_build_object('appetizers',jsonb_build_array(jsonb_build_object('id',t))) )
from (values (3),(5),(9)) t(t);

 t | exists
---+--------
 3 | t
 5 | t
 9 | f
```

Comment: For just a single top-level object, plain `@>` is simpler. I initially missed the restriction to appetizers and built a query for any number of top-level objects.