# Variable substitution for Postgres jsonpath operator like_regex?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, jsonpath

I want to query a JSONB array using a regex filter. Following the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE), I should be able to do:

```sql
WHERE jsonb_path_exists(
  data,
  '$.value[*] ? (@ like_regex $foo flag "i")',
  jsonb_build_object('foo', 'demo')
)
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "$foo" of jsonpath input
```

I think it's because `$` is a valid regex character?

Here is some demo data:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_data (fields) VALUES
     ('[{"value": "Sales"}]'),
     ('[{"value": "CEO Staff"}]'),
     ('[{"value": "Procurement"'),
     ('[{"value": "CEO Staff"}]');
```

I wish to query all that have a value containing `'ceo'`.

Comment: `where fields->0->>'value' ~* 'ceo';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem in current Postgres 16.0. Parameter substitution works for other [`jsonpath` operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-OP-TABLE) like `==`, but fails for `like_regex`. The manual does not seem to  mention this restriction, though.

I don't think this it related to the special meaning of `$` in regexp expressions (which would be enclosed in double quotes). The error kicks in earlier. Looks like parameter substitution is just not supported there.

Notably, the manual speaks of `value ==`**`value`**, but `string like_regex`**`string`** (bold emphasis mine). But that lead falls flat, as there is also `string starts with`**`string`**, and variable substitution works as expected there.

There is a **workaround**: build a `jsonpath` expression dynamically and work with the associated [Postgres operator **`@?`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl 
WHERE  data @? format('$[*].value ? (@ like_regex %s flag "i")', '"CEO"')::jsonpath;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DhWTZV1k)

Using (optional) [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) for convenient string concatenation. The string literal `'"CEO"'` can be replaced by an expression - the target use case I presume?
Then cast to `jsonpath`.

The plot twist: this is **superior** anyway. It can use an **index** - as opposed to using the function [`jsonb_path_exists()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.13.2.2.17.1.1.1)! (And the operator `@?` does not allow for parameter substitution to begin with.)
An index like (among others):

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl USING gin (data jsonb_path_ops);
```

Closely related (also look at the attached fiddle over there!):

- [Test given IDs for existence in any row of a JSON column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77311707/test-given-ids-for-existence-in-any-row-of-a-json-column/77312321#77312321)

Index usage is bound to operators internally, not functions. Some functions can be transformed by the query planner, but not in this case. Related:

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns/29245753#29245753)

Comment: Let me just preface this by saying that it's an honour to receive an answer like this. Thank you, sincerely. And yes, what I'm trying to do is build a parameterised query. I posted the same question on the DB Admins stack exchange and found out that variables can't be used in this context (more [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/332278/postgres-like-regex-with-variables/332283#332283)), accompanied with a suggestion, similar to yours. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the `fields` JSON array might contain more than one element and therefore I would first flatten using lateral join and then filter using the case-insensitive 'regexp-match' operator `~*`.

```sql
select fields, f -- or whatever else you might need
from table_data
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(fields) f
where f->>'value' ~* '\yCEO\y';
```

If `fields` JSON array always contains one element then simply

```sql
select fields from table_data
where fields->0->>'value' ~* '\yCEO\y';
```

DB Fiddle [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oJmBRfUAndZkEHsQTNssWQ/0)