# How to create tsvector in PostgreSQL for a table which has jsonb and "normal" columns

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have a table which has "normal" text columns and a single jsonb column and I want to be able to have full text search on all of them.

I understand that I can pass jsonb column to normal *to_tsvector* function. However *jsonb_to_tsvector* function has some additional options which are usefule in my situation (for example to exclude keys). Is it possible to create tsvector which combines text columns and data from json without keys?

Comment: while it would be better to normalize your data, you can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array

Comment: Please give a concrete example of what you like or don't like about each option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the results of different `to_tsvector` function calls:

```
to_tsvector(text_col) || to_tsvector(jsonb_col)
```