# Postgresql not using index on WHERE IN but works with WHERE =

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-14

I'm querying a table with a few millions rows. When I use a sub select with =

```sql
select *
from "parcels" 
where "parcel_id" = (select "parcel_id" 
                     from "parcels_properties" 
                     where "property_id" = '178528')
```

the **index will be used** and it returns in 2 secs.

This, obviously when the subquery has more than one results, I need to use `WHERE IN`. Then it won't use the index and gives me 10+ second.

```sql
select * 
from "parcels" 
where "parcel_id" in (select "parcel_id" 
                      from "parcels_properties" 
                      where "property_id" = '178528')
```

explain:

```
"Hash Join  (cost=82047.73..357097.98 rows=2019856 width=170)"
"  Hash Cond: ((parcels.parcel_id)::text = (parcels_properties.parcel_id)::text)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on parcels  (cost=0.00..241975.11 rows=4039711 width=170)"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=82045.23..82045.23 rows=200 width=38)"
"        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=82043.23..82045.23 rows=200 width=38)"
"              Group Key: (parcels_properties.parcel_id)::text"
"              ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..81970.73 rows=28999 width=38)"
"                    Workers Planned: 2"
"                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on parcels_properties  (cost=0.00..78070.83 rows=12083 width=38)"
"                          Filter: ((property_id)::text = '178528'::text)"
```

On line 3 of this explain, a `Seq Scan` on `parcels` table is used, instead of the `parcel_id index` ?

One more thing, **this is on the AWS RDS**.

If I run this same SQL on my **local** database with almost same setup (only RDS is v14, local is v12) it **uses the index** and returns instantly.

Created index on parcels table:

- parcel_id

Created index on parcels_properties table:

- parcel_id
- property_id

So could anyone help me out with this issue?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Doing so will sorta force index scan on Parcels table

```
SET enable_seqscan = OFF;

SELECT *
FROM parcels p
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM parcels_properties pp
    WHERE pp.parcel_id = p.parcel_id AND property_id = '178528'
);
```

Comment: What's your index and execute plan? could you show us more information?

Comment: How many rows did you get when you use in?

Comment: @D-Shih mostly one row but sometimes can be multiple.

Comment: Please edit your question and restore the same column names you were originally using.  Your edit has invalidated my answer.  Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51476889/15603477 you  should read from buttom to up.
so can you share the full explain code.

Answer (score 1):

You never told us which indices you have defined, but in any case I would express your query using exists logic:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM parcels p
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM parcels_properties pp
    WHERE pp.parcel_id = p.parcel_id AND property_id = '12345'
);
```

This query should benefit from the following index on `parcels_properties`:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_pp ON parcel_properties (property_id, parcel_id);
```

Comment: I would put `property_id` first in the index since it is in the subquery predicate: `CREATE INDEX idx_pp ON parcel_properties (property_id, parcel_id);`

Comment: @RadimBača I'll agree with your point, I have changed my answer.

Comment: hi @TimBiegeleisen I have updated more details.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen problem is, result from `FROM parcels_properties pp
    WHERE pp.parcel_id = p.parcel_id AND property_id = '12345'` can be multiple so I have to use `WHERE IN`

Comment: No, you _don't_ have to use `WHERE IN`, you can use my query instead.

Comment: seems still doing the `->  Seq Scan on parcels p  (cost=0.00..241975.11 rows=4039711 width=960)`

Comment: What is wrong with that?  The query doesn't know which parcel to retain until it has done a lookup for each one against the properties table.  A scan on parcels is acceptable here.

Comment: but a same database structure on my local db will use a parcels.parcel_id index scan. which is 10 times faster.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone might have this same problem in the future.
Try [VACUUM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-vacuum.html) your database.

I did a full `VACUUM` of the database and it worked.

```
 vacuumdb --echo --full --verbose --analyze -h yourdbhost -p 5432 -U your username -d yourdbname
```