# Add and use index for jsonb with nested arrays

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, jsonb, postgresql-performance

In my PostgreSQL 11.11 I have one `jsonb` column that holds objects like this:

```
{
   "dynamicFields":[
      {
         "name":"200",
         "hidden":false,
         "subfields":[
            {
               "name":"a",
               "value":"Subfield a"
            },
            {
               "name":"b",
               "value":"Subfield b"
            }           
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

`dynamicFields` is an array and `subfields` is also an array and I having performance issues when hitting selects like this:

```
select *
from my_table a
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_column -> 'dynamicFields') df
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(df -> 'subfields') sf
where df ->> 'name' = '200' and sf ->> 'name' = 'a'
```

The performance issues live mostly in the `subfield`. I have already added an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_my_index ON my_table USING gin ((marc->'dynamicFields') jsonb_path_ops);
```

How can I add an index for the `subfields` inside the `dynamicFields`?
The query above is just one example, I use it a lot in joins with other tables in the database. And I also know the `@>` operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already have a very good index to support your query.
Make use of it with the [`jsonb` "contains" operator" **`@>`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  marc->'dynamicFields' @> '[{"name": "200", "subfields":[{"name": "a"}]}]';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bbee50c9108dc630b641bb8232ba3d00)*

Carefully match the structure of the JSON object in the table. Then rows are selected cheaply using the index.
You can then extract whatever parts you need from qualifying rows.

Detailed instructions:

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)

If one of the filters is very selective on its own, it might be faster to split the two conditions like in your original. Either way, both variants should be *fast*:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  marc->'dynamicFields' @> '[{"name": "200"}]'
AND    marc->'dynamicFields' @> '[{"subfields":[{"name": "a"}]}]';
```

Comment: I would be interested how both queries compare in your setting. Can you report times for both, and your original?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try to use these in the queries as much as possible and let you know.

Comment: I did the same query but adding the @> for some filtering in the where clause and it went 55 seconds to 60ms.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been trying to do, but I `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` does not tell me that the index is being used. I modified your fiddle to demo this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a49d8f77d271b019af39aad95c354487 --what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @ManuelKaufmann: Postgres won't use indexes for such a tiny test table. Indexes only pay for bigger tables. You can force the issue for the tiny test with `SET enable_seqscan = off;` See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14555618/939860. Modified fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6a37e5ff913c77c6068564f454ad174f (Or test with a much bigger table.)

Answer (score -2):

Index is for enhancing query performance on tables. Index can only be done on table columns and considering those columns that will be used in table join and where clause makes the indexing significant. For a jsonb column you can use create index on table_name using gin(column_name, jsonb_path_ops).

Comment: Yes, you can use a GIN index, but you should have said how. An index can also be defined on an expression. The question is not about joins, so promulgating general ideas about indexing is probably not going to help solve the problem.