# Does gorm use indexes by default?

Tags: postgresql, go-gorm

I would like to utilize indexes in db

Does gorm use index by default on it's queries or I should specify manually?

```
type User struct {
ID uint
Name string `gorm:"uniqueIndex:idx_user_name"
}
```

**Option A**

```
var user User
db.Find(&user)
```

*from terminal I don't see if option A is using index*

**Option B**

```
import "gorm.io/hints"

db.Clauses(hints.UseIndex("idx_user_name")).Find(&User{})
// SELECT * FROM `users` USE INDEX (`idx_user_name`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres [does not support `USE INDEX` hinting syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/309786/1048572). It will automatically choose the appropriate index. Using `gorm` won't change that.